# Multidimensional function as manifold

Tags: calculus, manifolds

Given $g(x,y)=2x^2+y^2-1$. I know that $g^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold. But why?
Could you please give me a step by step answer so i can try to understand how its done and try it on my own next time.

Thank you

Comment: It's not entirely straight-forward, generally. You have to make sure there are no singularities, for instance. Take the example $f(x, y) = x^3 - 2x^2 + x - y^2$. This does _not_ give a manifold, because $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ self-intersects. Ruling out such self-intersections is not always easy. Of course, in your case, one could "cheat" (using information you have access to is not really cheating) and know what your set looks like in advance (it's an ellipse). From there we could construct the charts necessary to prove manifold-ness.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, this can be seen as a consequence of the following result :

> Let $f : V \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function over an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $S=f^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$. If, for all $x \in S$, $Df(x) \neq 0$, then S is a manifold.

The proof of this uses the implicit fonctions theorem to show that $S$ is locally the graph of some  smooth function $g$.